# Unique arrays in list python

Tags: python, numpy

How can I get the unique arrays from such a list below?

```
data =[np.array([ 10, 17]),
       np.array([ 10, 17]),
       np.array([ 1, 17, 34]),
       np.array([ 1, 17, 34]),
       np.array([ 20, 50, 38]),
       np.array([ 20, 50, 38]),
       np.array([ 20, 50, 40])]

expected = [ np.array([ 10, 17]),
             np.array([ 1, 17, 34]),
             np.array([ 20, 50, 38]),
             np.array([ 20, 50, 40])]
```

I applied `set(data)` but it gave me the error;

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

I have got some ideas like:

- Looping and appending an empty list and comparing the next candidate by using '==' with the prior list and so on.
- Applying a mathematical operation on the arrays which gives unique output. Then removing the duplicates.
- Using tobytes for each array for making them one line. And removing duplicates again.

All sounds inefficient to me. Any easy way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy arrays are unhashable but tuples are, so you can map them to tuples, cast to set, then map back to numpy arrays.

```
out = list(map(np.array, set(map(tuple, data))))
```

If the order the arrays appear in the list is important, you could also use `dict.fromkeys`:

```
out = list(map(np.array, dict.fromkeys(map(tuple, data)).keys()))
```

Output:

```
[array([10, 17]),
 array([ 1, 17, 34]),
 array([20, 50, 38]),
 array([20, 50, 40])]
```